# Troubleshooting Basic Javascript into HTML DIVs

Tags: javascript, html

Years since I've touched JavaScript, but I cannot seem to reuse this previously-working JavaScript into a new HTML file... everything is in one folder. Nonetheless, nothing appears in the web page when opened into a browser.

I think it's something wrong I'm doing in the HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Traits.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<div align="center" id="id1"></div>
<div align="center" id="id2"></div>
<div align="center" id="id3"></div>
<div align="center" id="id4"></div>
<div align="center" id="id5"></div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the adjacent Traits.js file...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                
Date.prototype.getDOY = function() {
var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
return Math.ceil((this - onejan) / 86400000);
}
var pri="Title 1";
var hu="Title 2";
var cpri="Title 3";
var safe="Safety";
var wk=1;
var pwk=6;
var hwk=1;
var cwk=1;
var swk=1;
var today = new Date();
var daynum = today.getDOY();
var yr=today.getFullYear();
var yrs=(yr-2012);
var dys=(yrs*365);
var ldys=Math.floor(yrs/4);

var tdays=(ldys+dys+daynum-14);     //Sets the beginning of a cycle for ID2 Traits.
var cdays=tdays-113;                //Sets the beginning of a cycle for ID3 Traits. 
                                    //Adjust these last two lines as necessary to change which week is used to display for ID3.
                                    //Add 7 to the number being subtracted to go back a week or subtract 7 to go forward a week. 
var oedays=daynum+4;                //Sets the day of the year for ID1.
if (yr==2015) {oedays=oedays-365;}  //This will need to be adjusted for leap years in 2020. 

tdays=(tdays+28);                   //Resets tdays so that we started with 1 on 29 June 2013.

while (tdays>70)
{
         tdays=(tdays-70);
}
wk=Math.floor((tdays/7)+1);         //Makes a week 1-10 for ID2.


while (cdays>63)
{
         cdays=(cdays-63);
}
cwk=Math.floor((cdays/7)+1);        //Makes a week 1-9 for ID3.


if (wk==1) {pri="Personal Accountability";}
if (wk==2) {pri="Questioning Attitude";}
if (wk==3) {pri="Effective Safety Communication";}
if (wk==4) {pri="Leadership Safety Values and Actions";}
if (wk==5) {pri="Decision-Making";}
if (wk==6) {pri="Respectful Work Environment";}
if (wk==7) {pri="Continuous Learning";}
if (wk==8) {pri="Problem Identification and Resolution";}
if (wk==9) {pri="Environment for Raising Concerns";}
if (wk==10) {pri="Work Processes";}

if (cwk==1) {cpri="Leaders Demonstrate Alignment on a Commitment to Excellence";}
if (cwk==2) {cpri="Strong First-Line Supervision Is Key to Success";}
if (cwk==3) {cpri="Personnel Are Qualified for Their Jobs";}
if (cwk==4) {cpri="Schedules Are Realistic and Understood";}
if (cwk==5) {cpri="Construction of a Nuclear Plant Has Special Requirements";}
if (cwk==6) {cpri="Personnel Safety Is Highly Valued";}
if (cwk==7) {cpri="The Plant Is Built As Designed";}
if (cwk==8) {cpri="Deviations and Concerns Are Identified, Communicated, and Resolved";}
if (cwk==9) {cpri="The Transition to Plant Operation Is Started Early";}


$('#id1').html("<font size='3' color='red' face='Arial, Helvetica'><a href='Calendar%20" + yr + "%20Calendar.pdf#page=" + oedays +"'>Today's " + yr + " Calendar: </a></font><font size='3' face='Arial, Helvetica'>Opens the calendar to today's date.<br></font><hr>");

$('#id2').html("<font size='3' face='Arial, Helvetica'>ID2 Topic: </font><font size='3' color='red' face='Arial, Helvetica'><a href='Image%20" + wk +".jpg'>" + pri +"</a></font><br><hr>");

$('#id3').html("<font size='3' face='Arial, Helvetica'>ID3 Topic: </font><font size='3' color='red' face='Arial, Helvetica'><a href='Topical%20%23" + cwk +".pdf'>" + cpri +"</a></font><br><hr>");

$('#id4').html("<font size='3' color='red' face='Arial, Helvetica'><a href='ID4%20Document.pdf'>ID4 Doucment</a></font><br><hr>");

});
```

Please teach me...

Comment: This is a good time to start using your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  In the browser's script debugger, when you step through the code, which operation first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: Your JS uses jQuery. Have you included jquery? You should see the error in the console...

Comment: Side note: this is not good code. For one, it requires you to update it (see comment "This will need to be adjusted for leap years in 2020."). The coder seems to have been unaware of the remainder operator (`%`) or arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have included the jQuery library before your Traits.js file in your HTML document. You can include jQuery like this before the closing :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Script Order: Ensure that the  tag referencing Traits.js comes after including jQuery, as shown in the code below:

html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Traits.js"></script>
```

Document Ready: Make sure that the HTML page is fully loaded before the JavaScript in Traits.js executes. You are using $(document).ready(), which should wait for the DOM to be ready. If you still encounter issues, try moving the script tag just before the closing  tag, like this:

html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Traits.js"></script>
```

i hope i could help

Comment: This fixed it... jQuery was missing. Thank you!